# How to check if Hibernate is getting an object from the L1 cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a legacy application which in various places calls `repository.findById(...)` in a loop. This results in hundreds of calls to the database. Since Hibernate loads all entities into the L1 cache by default I thought I could fix this performance issue by calling `repository.findByIdIn(...)` before the loop and so save the repeated database calls. But I can't find a way to find if the entities were returned from the DB or the cache. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to inform you that there are no APIs that can check if a given entity is loaded from L1 cache , L2 cache or DB.

The most you can do is verify it from the log which configure the following loggers 's logging levels :

- `org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener` to `trace` level
- `org.hibernate.SQL` to `debug` level

If the entity is loaded from DB , it will log out the SQL that is used to fetch this entity and :

```
 Object not resolved in any cache: [org.foo.bar.#1]
```

If the entity is loaded from L2 cache , it will log out :

```
Resolved object in second-level cache:[org.foo.bar.#1]
```

If none of the above are logged , it means the entity is loaded from L1 cache.